# Tracking cut and paste changes between worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am capturing changes made in 2 sheets(Active, Inactive), recording the changes in a 3rd sheet (Change Log), all within a single workbook. The purpose is to track changes to the sheets capturing the sheet name, cell that has changed, old value, new value, user name and time stamp.

However, when I cut from one of the sheets and paste into the other, the sheet name captured is the same - the sheet into which the information is being pasted, where as the first entry needs to capture the name of the sheet from which the information is cut. The cell references are captured correctly.

Eg. I cut from the sheet named 'Active', D1, and paste into the sheet named 'Inactive, D6. The change log records the first action (cut) location incorrectly as 'Inactive D1' and the second action (paste) correctly as 'Inactive D6'.

How to I ensure the name of the sheet being cut from is captured correctly?

Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
Dim oldValue As String


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next

Set logsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Change Log")
logsheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & " - " & Target.Address(0, 0)
logsheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = oldValue
logsheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
logsheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Environ("username")
logsheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Now

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next

oldValue = Target.Value
oldAddress = Target.Address
'MsgBox Target.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ActiveSheet.Name` To `Target.Parent.Name`

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you!

Comment: if this worked for you @PurplePoppy, consider marking as answered.